# How to clear all checkboxes in ListActivity - or how to access each shown row?

Tags: android, listactivity

I used ListActivity to create rows with checkboxes.

How can I clear or select all boxes at once AFTER the list has been created initially?

During creation in getView I just have the line:

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
```

**But how can I access all the shown rows after they have been created outside getView?**

This is how I create each row:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
                XXX element = (XXX) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                element.selectedFlag = buttonView.isChecked() ? Constants.STATUS_SELECTED
                    : Constants.STATUS_UNSELECTED;
            }
            });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);

    return view;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the following link :

the perfect solution for your

http://www.androiddom.com/2011/02/android-shopping-cart-tutorial.html

See the code of ProductAdapter class

> ```
> private boolean mShowCheckbox;
> ```

Later:

> ```
> if(!mShowCheckbox) {
>    item.productCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>   } else {
>    if(curProduct.selected == true)
>     item.productCheckbox.setChecked(true);
>    else
>     item.productCheckbox.setChecked(false);
>   }
> ```

Comment: Hi, this looks like a great tutorial - I understand the checking part, how do I access the item variables from outside the getView method? I do not know how to access the item AFTER they have been created. Thanks very much for this really good tutorial!